# After using mkdir() to create a folder how do I have the program save files and other information into the the new folder

Tags: c++, fstream, mkdir

So this program creates a folder in the program itself with is great but how would I have it save the new file in the folder it just created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string newFolder = "Example";


int main()
{

_mkdir((newFolder.c_str()));

fstream inout;
inout.open("hello.txt",ios::out);
inout << " This is a test";
inout.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create pathname that includes the directory and filename. Since `std::string` provides an override for `operator+` it's as easy as hot apple pie. The following should help you get on your way.

```
inout.open(newFolder + "/hello.txt");
```

Comment: You should check the return value of the call to `open` to see if it's failing. The text file you see may be an old one.

Comment: Alright that worked great after I changed something that I overlooked after I placed it in the program thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the newly created directory to become the current directory, you can also try adding:

_chdir((newFolder.c_str()));

after calling _mkdir